# ANDROID - Save multiple images in database

Tags: android, database, save

I have an app in which I have to combine parts of clothes. To understand me better I have given a screenshot below. The thing is, that i am having problems on how to get these images and save them in my database. Of course i faced errors.

```
public class ViewOutfit extends Activity {

private DatabaseHandler handler;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_outfit);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    final ImageView im1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1);
    im1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra("image1")));
    im1.toString();

    final ImageView im2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im2);
    im2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra("image2")));
    im2.toString();

    final ImageView im3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.im3);
    im3.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra("image3")));
    im3.toString();

    final ImageView im4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.im4);
    im4.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra("image4")));
    im4.toString();

    final ImageView im5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.im5);
    im5.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra("image5")));
    im5.toString();

    final ImageView im6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.im6);
    im6.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getStringExtra("image6")));
    im6.toString();



    ImageButton btn_save_outfit = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_combine);
    btn_save_outfit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            im1.getDrawable().toString();
            im2.getDrawable().toString();
            im3.getDrawable().toString();
            im4.getDrawable().toString();
            im5.getDrawable().toString();
            im6.getDrawable().toString();


            Outfits outfits = new Outfits();
            outfits.setImage1(String.valueOf(im1));
            outfits.setImage2(String.valueOf(im2));
            outfits.setImage3(String.valueOf(im3));
            outfits.setImage4(String.valueOf(im4));
            outfits.setImage5(String.valueOf(im5));
            outfits.setImage6(String.valueOf(im6));

            Boolean added = handler.addOutfit(outfits);
            if(added){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Outfit added." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String log = "Id: "+ outfits.getID()+" ,Image1: " + outfits.getImage1() + " ,Image2: " + outfits.getImage2()

                        + ",Image3:" + outfits.getImage3() + ",Image4:" + outfits.getImage5() + ",Image6:" +outfits.getImage6();

                Log.d("Image1: ", log);


            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Outfit not added. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }});
}
```

[image: User choice of clothes]

Comment: why would you want to save them in a database instead of a filesystem ? I think it would be better to save them into the storage of the phone. just add to each image a unique filename and save that filename in the database.

Comment: I'd save the images on local storage if they are from a remote location, and then store their location in the DB. If your images in the res/drawable folder i.e. ship with the app - then just store the Id's in an array, or the DB.

Comment: These images are saved in app's database. Then i have showed them in GridView.

Comment: @Ntina.Tsif: go with saving them each one as it is in each listView item.

Comment: @Fllo any thoughts my friend?

Comment: What return the Toast, is that successfull with weird value or `Outfit not added.`?